# How to save a CKRecord to CloudKit with multiple type of information with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, cloudkit, ckrecord

If I was trying to save a CKRecord that had a title(String) and a Location(CLLocation) together so that when they were fetched, they would be downloaded as a pair would they both be in the same record or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a record that contains both fields would be the appropriate way to do it.

CloudKit allows multiple fields of various types to exist in one record type. Here's an example of the CloudKit dashboard showing a record type with both a string and a location:

[image]

To save your record, you would do something like this:

```
myRecord["TestString"] = title as CKRecordValue
myRecord["TestLocationCoords"] = location as CKRecordValue
```

Where `title` is a `String` and `location` is a `CLLocation`.

Comment: can you please show the full code one should use? I'm in the same situation as the person asking the question.